# JNI configuration for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI and I have successfully executed a standalone JNI application in Windows 7,writing the C++ code in Visual Studio 2012. But when I try to create a new JNI project in apache-tomcat/webapps folder, and try to execute the java class, I get the following error-

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: adjni.getStringArrays
(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)[[Ljava/lang/String;
        at adjni.getStringArrays(Native Method)
        at adjni.main(adjni.java:13)
```

Though I have gone through a lot of similar problems, I haven't been able to find a suitable solution. I don't know which environment variables to be set and what other changes need to be made. I think the problem is that the java class is not able to find the dll file but I do not know how to solve the problem. Please help .

Answer (score 0):

In general the UnsatisfiedLinkError had happened when you tried to call the native method before you called `System.loadLibrary("your library name");`

The following notes may help you:
- make sure that your web application load the library during initialization of your web application (ex: in your ServletContextListener implementation class, contextInitialized method).
- make sure that your native library file accessible from tomcat, check the classpath string (ex: -Djava.library.path or LD_LIBRARY_PATH (linux) or  PATH (Windows)).

how did you run your application in standalone ? can you write your command line ? where did you put the native library ?

Comment: I executed the standalone using Visual C++.

Comment: I mean the Java standalone application and how you include your .dll file in your run command line

Answer (score 0):

Include the dll file in the /bin folder and place the java file and the class file in the /WEB-INF/classes folder. This worked for me.